# Drawing arc with coordinates in 2D in asymptote

Tags: diagrams, asymptote, venn-diagrams

I've seen [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125155/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-asymptote) for 3D, but I cannot get this working in 2D.

Here is my code:

```
pair O1 = origin;
pair O2 = (1.5,0);
pair O3 = (1,-1);
pair C = (0.75,sqrt(7)/4);
pair F = (0.75,-sqrt(7)/4);
pair E = (1,0);
pair B = (0,-1);
pair D = (((1/20)*(25-2*sqrt(55))),((1/8)+(1/40)*(2*sqrt(55)-25)));
pair A = (((1/20)*(25+2*sqrt(55))),((1/8)+(1/40)*(-2*sqrt(55)-25)));

label("$C$",C,N);
label("$F$",F,E);
label("$E$",E,NE);
label("$B$",B,SW);
label("$D$",D,W);
label("$A$",A,SE);

draw(circle(O1,1));
draw(circle(O2,1));
draw(circle(O3,1));
draw(arc(O1,E,C),blue+linewidth(5));
```

I want to trace out a thick bold line along some of the intersections. Is there a way to do something like

```
draw(arc(center,coordinate1,coordinate2),linewidth(2));
```

to trace out a path? This is as opposed to specifying start and end angles. For instance,

```
draw(arc(O1,E,C),linewidth(2));
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `size` (or `unitsize`) operator.
Add, say, `size(300);` in the beginning and you already have
a thick blue arc `EC`. Or do you need something else?

Comment: My original code has a size operator. I only included the stuff for this venn-like diagram as there are other things going on as well. There is no arc being output, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Yes, this is exactly the way to do it. Is this what you want?

```
// darcs.asy :
size(200);
// Drawing arc with coordinates in 2D in asymptote  

texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");
pair O1 = (0,0);// origin;
pair O2 = (1.5,0);
pair O3 = (1,-1);
pair A = (((1/20)*(25+2*sqrt(55))),((1/8)+(1/40)*(-2*sqrt(55)-25)));
pair B = (0,-1);
pair C = (0.75,sqrt(7)/4);
pair D = (((1/20)*(25-2*sqrt(55))),((1/8)+(1/40)*(2*sqrt(55)-25)));
pair EE = (1,0);
pair F = (0.75,-sqrt(7)/4);

pen linePen=darkblue+1bp;
pen markPenA=red+3bp+opacity(0.8);
pen markPenB=green+3bp+opacity(0.8);


draw(circle(O1,1),linePen);
draw(circle(O2,1),linePen);
draw(circle(O3,1),linePen);
draw(arc(O1,EE,C),markPenA);
draw(arc(O1,C,EE),markPenB);

dot(new pair[]{A,B,C,D,EE,F},darkblue,UnFill);
label("$A$",A,SE);
label("$B$",B,SW);
label("$\,C$",C,N);
label("$D$",D,NW);
label("$E$",EE,NE);
label("$F$",F,E);
```

Note: names `N,S,E,W,NE,NW,SE,SW` predefined to be used in `label`s placements,
so it is better to avoid redefinition and use, for example, `EE` instead of `E`.

Comment: If we were to add an arrow to the arcs, it would make them go counterclockwise. How can we make the arcs go clockwise?

Comment: @Ashmit Dutta: Key words: `BeginArrow`, `EndArrow`, `MidArrow`, `reverse`,
`CW`,`CCW`.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler Asymptote code for very old question.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
real r=2;
path c1=circle((0,0),r);
path c2=circle((3,0),r);
path c3=circle((2,-2.5),r);
draw(c2^^c3);

pair A=intersectionpoints(c1,c2)[0]; 
pair B=intersectionpoints(c1,c3)[1]; 
path g=arc((0,0),A,B);
path h=arc((0,0),A,B,CW);
draw(g,blue+1pt);
draw(h,green+1pt);

dot("$A$",align=2N,A,red);
dot("$B$",align=SE,B,red);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```